# pfsense: squid transparent proxy not working in bridge mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, firewall, pfsense

I have installed the latest version of `pfsense`.

I have setup it up in bridge mode after creating a rule any for lan and wan respectively. 
I have setup the squid on transparent proxy mode with `ssl` but if I enable the transparent option then internet is not working in the client machine.

Why is it not working?

Comment: If you would give us more details about the configurations, it would help.

Comment: Setup the firewall in bridge mode  and install the squid3 with transparent proxy and ssl enable. in squid,transparent,ssl  listen the LAN port and in firewall created the LAN and WAN to any rule and outbound setup as manual mode( i used [link] (http://www.pdfdrive.net/setup-a-transparent-firewall-filtering-bridge-with-pfsense-e2170780.html)